# finding the correct SQL-query

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have some issues with SQL (Im really bad at it) and maybe someone can help me find the right command.

the table name is **enddate**
with following attributes

```
ID int
old_end_date date
name varchar
```

im trying to get the last old date in the table by the name

i tried this :

```
SELECT old_end_date from enddate WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM enddate)
```

but its not filtered by the name..

thank you in advance :)

Comment: `mysql` or `postgresql` ? Those 2 are different.

Comment: [mre], means that you need to share some sample data, and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql 8

you can do ROW_NUMBER

```
SELECT * from ( 
   SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY old_end_date desc) rn 
   from enddate
) t
WHERE rn = 1 AND name = "hello"
```

If you only want  one name

```
SELECT * 
FROM enddate
WHERE name = "hello"
ORDER BY old_end_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: sorry i didnt explained it good enough, I need a clause where i can filter it by the name like where name = "hello"

Comment: simply add the where clause to the rn = 1

Answer (score 0):

here is one way and simplest way. this way you don't need window functions:

```
select * 
from enddate
where name = 'hello'
order by old_end_date desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: "but its not filtered by the name.." ??